# How to change wifi credentials of multiple ESP8266 together

Tags: esp8266, wifi, library, network

I need to change WiFi credentials of multiple ESP8266 in one go, without needing to change passwords for each of them individually. I know there is a WiFiManager library, which makes your ESP8266 access point when not connected to any network, but that will require me configure each of them individually.

How can I save the fatigue of changing their wifi credentials individually? All of them needs to connect to the same network, whose password is recently changed.

Comment: You could implement a "provisioning service". Kind of like WiFiManager but in reverse. If you can't connect to the real access point then connect to the provisioning access point, from which you can then obtain the credentials to connect to the real access point. Of course you just move your security weakness to the provisioning access point which can never have the details changed...

Answer (score 1):

you can reconfigure your router, or whatever network mode you are using, with auto-login to the MAC addresses of your ESPs.

And then if you provide the MACs of the corresponding ESPs, and change your WiFi credentials, then you don't need to configure the ESPs individually. It will auto-connect itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have your devices always try to download a config file from a webserver you control.  If the config file exists and has new wifi credentials then it can update itself and reset.  When you actually change the password for the AP all the devices will already have the new password.